# Should I create a new Form or use form alter?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm very new to Drupal. I've been handed over a Drupal 7 project. In the project, there's a form to create a new record into database. However it's using `hook_form_alter` instead of creating from scratch. The form is called as `node/add/<something>` as a page. Similar to first few steps of [this](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2013/01/22/drupal-7-how-override-forms-using-custom-template#.UiazVzZpmqE) tutorial.

I'm not sure however if this is the correct Drupal way, or should I just rewrite it into a block, as I want to have it shown on .... at least two pages?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction is simple:

- If you need to add some fields to an existing form, and keep all of it's original functionality (or at least most of it), use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).
- If you need to create a totally new experience, put it under different path and create form from scratch, like shown in [Examples for developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples)
- If you feel you need totally new form under already occupied path, think again as it might cripple existing functionality.Feel free to ask more specific question then.

Then, if you want a form at 2 pages, you have 2 choices:

- If form will be the only significant element on these pages, make it a page (or pages) with [`hook_menu`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
- If there are supposed to be other forms, submitted independently, wrap it into a block.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, Molot.
I had a clear picture of the distinctions now. Guess I will have to customize the default node add/edit form.

Thus, about the choices, the form will co-exist on top of the page together of the rest of blocks. Further, on one page there would be two forms on top separated by tabs.

So I think choice#2 would be a better idea? How would you suggest I wrap it into a block? Structure > Blocks? 
Currently I'm using a customized template to override the form page.

Comment: @NineAllexis If you can draw a quick mockup of what you need, please post another question :) I don't quite get it now, and comments aren't a good place to ask and answer anyway.

Comment: Okay! I've posted another question. Thanks for the help.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84558/extended-default-form-inside-block-possible