# Extended default form inside block, possible?

Tags: 7, forms

Ok. So I have a content type, let's say "My favorite places".
So naturally Drupal has a form to create new "favorite place" at node/add/my-favorite-places which appears as a page. I managed to create a customized template for this form my_favorite_places-node-form.tpl.php following this very helpful thread. 
[How do you theme a content type's create/edit form in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33253/how-do-you-theme-a-content-types-create-edit-form-in-drupal-7)

I'd like to use this form in several pages on my site. So I was thinking to make it into a block. In below mockups, My favorite places = Content Type A.

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Pushing my luck Page 3]

However......
I had some experiences customizing front page for anonymous users showing login & register form at the same time, which doesn't run properly with a block (messaging issue). An expert mentioned that form rendering calls should never be fired from inside blocks.

So, I was wondering whether this is a good idea. And if so, how should I do that, if possible without installing another contrib module.

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use forms inside blocks but its always best to run them through Drupal's form API to benefit from their security layers. Alejandro's suggestion to use drupal_get_form is right but you might find it easier to use the [Advanced Form Block](https://drupal.org/project/afb) module which does exactly what you are asking, including creating multiple form blocks of the same content type. You create a block through their interface, chosing the content-type you want to create, and its then available to place through blocks admin or context, etc.

Comment: I guess I have no other choice other than that module. At least for now... Thanks schnippy.

Answer (score 0):

Using php inside blocks or simply pouring your database with php used to be bad practice.

Said that, the function toy are looking for is drupal get form:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7

Comment: Thanks Alejandro. I used it before to combine the login + reg forms together on front page.